# List of Apple devices using the home indicator?

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm developing a mobile app and need to know whether or not a [home indicator](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*UCqVtMc5StTebIRUvfHSDg.png) is present on the device I am on (in ios cases). I know that it exists on iPhone X and higher versions. But I can't find out an official list of devices implementing that new feature. Is there one?

That way, I could adapt my UI design according to wether or not the device I detect belongs to that list. (using com.diamonddevgroup.device.Device API)

Just in case, I'm developping using codenameone.

Thanks

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow to host your images. Just hit the "image" button and drag your image onto it,

Comment: What UI changes do you need to make? Depending on your reason, maybe the view safe areas would be enough?

Answer (score 3):

I added support for handling that.

Once the update has been approved by Codename One team, update your **Device** library and call below:

```
boolean isNotch = Device.isNotch();
```

You can check the GitHub page for the library [here](https://github.com/diamonddevgroup/CN1-Device).

And you can follow the status of the library update approval with this [pull request](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOneLibs/pull/28). It is approved once its status has changed to **`Closed`**.

Leave a comment on this answer or create an issue [here](https://github.com/diamonddevgroup/CN1-Device/issues) if you encounter any problem with the library.

Comment: Great job! This was merged and updated. Caches will take roughly 3 hours to flush.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely be using the [safe areas](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area) with [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to properly layout your views.

But in the case you want to do *device specific* work, [this](https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit) library is fantastic for knowing about your user's current device.